# how to read internet status on splash android

Tags: android, networking

I need to detect whether the Android device is connected or disconnected to the internet on splash... if there's no connection, the application won't open.. i have try many time.. but i failed..  this is my splash's source code :

```
private Handler splashHandler = new Handler();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Runnable r = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Intent brain = new Intent(Splash.this, MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(brain);
            finish();
        }
    };
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    splashHandler.postDelayed(r, 2000);
}

public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

if there's someone help me and give me a source code.. tell me where i must put it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this SO Post: [Detect whether there is an Internet connection available on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available)

Here is what your code should look like:

```
private Handler splashHandler = new Handler();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Runnable r = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Intent brain = new Intent(Splash.this, MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(brain);
            finish();
        }
    };
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    if(isNetworkAvailable())
        splashHandler.postDelayed(r, 2000);
    else {
        //Notify user they aren't connected
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You aren't connected to the internet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //close the app
        finish();
    }
}

public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onResume();
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
      = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

As stated in the link above, you'll also need to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/android-network-connectivity-broadcastreceiver). It's a `BroadcastReciver` with action `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.` and it allows to the system whenever a change in the network connectivity occurs.

I hope it helps.